# continuous wavelet transform for csv file with python

Tags: python, csv, continuous, wavelet

I need help from someone who is good at cwt to help me. I want to perform CWT on a csv file with signal data, and then after processing the data file, to save it as a processed csv file, but I am stuck, and cannot seem to make it work.

Here is my code, hope someone can check for me and give me some advice:

```
import pywt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#pywt.cwt(data, scales, wavelet)¶
file_path = ("C://Users/RichardS/PycharmProjects/FYP/train_data.csv")
df = pd.read_csv(file_path)


x = df.iloc[:,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26]]
y = np.sin(2*np.pi*x/40)

coef, freqs=pywt.cwt(y,np.arange(0, 1024, 1),'mexh')
plt.matshow(coef)
plt.show(coef)
```

The error it shows is:

RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
j = np.arange(scale * (x[-1] - x[0]) + 1) / (scale * step)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/RichardS/PycharmProjects/FYP/cwt.py", line 14, in 
coef, freqs=pywt.cwt(y,np.arange(0, 1024, 1),'mexh')
File "C:\Users\RichardS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pywt_cwt.py", line 154, in cwt
int_psi_scale = int_psi[j][::-1]
IndexError: index -2147483648 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1024

Comment: FYI instead of writing `[1, 2, 3, ..., 26]`, you could use `list(range(1, 27))`

Comment: i write this is because my data files i have to selectively choose the columns as only some columns are useful out of the many other columns. So does it mean I can write like x = df.iloc[:,[list(range(1,27)] to achieve the same goal?

Comment: you need to drop square parenthesis before list like this: `x = df.iloc[: ,list(range(1,27)]`, but yes

Comment: if i use this df.iloc[: ,list(range(1,27)], i realized the 26th column is replaced as 27. So that means which column i end i have to add 1 to it?

Comment: The first argument of the range is an included lower bound, but the second argument is an excluded upper bound, so `range(a, b)` will give you `[a, a+1, a+2, ..., b-2, b-1]`